# Links have turned blue

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Looks like all the user links went, but only the visited links for questions.

[image: main page screenshot]

Things are a bit weird on meta too.

On questions this includes the dotted line, not just the title/link:

[image: question screenshot]

Comment: Bug? Or... [status-completed?](http://meta.cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/2073/link-contrast-is-too-low-on-meta)

Comment: @Shog9 Contrast was only too low on meta!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

We'd theorized that links taste better when blue, a subtle effect caused by a mental association with fake blueberry flavorings. But we were wrong. Instead, we got a pungent cyanobacteria aroma.

The original link color has been restored. [Details on Meta Stack Exchange](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/259185/problems-with-sff-and-seasoned-advice-se-css/259186#259186)