# Links became really blue again

Tags: bug, status-completed, design

Is it intentional this time or is it a recurrence of this:

[Links have turned blue](https://cooking.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/2075/links-have-turned-blue)

It looks the same:

[image]

As a note, these are the **unvisited** links for me.

Comment: I'm sure it's another bug. Post on main meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/263452/problems-with-sff-css-round-ii

Comment: @Jefromi No need.

Comment: @AnnaLear I meant "here's a post on main meta", sorry!

Comment: @Jefromi Whoops, my bad. I misread. :)

Answer (score 3):

Alas, that was not intentional but rather [an oversight on my part](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/263464/155160).

Should be fixed now.